# Is bulk create possible in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Let's assume that we have a model named Item (fields don't matter) and we want to create 200 items at once through an API call. We would prefer to hit the DB once and not 200 times. Passing a list of dictionaries to the viewset through request.data seems to not do the trick as the created items have slightly different creation time.

Can I create 200 items at once hitting the DB once in DRF?

Answer (score 0):

you can try follow like this [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on where exactly you would use it in your code? Imagine someone that wants to create 2 items. They would make a POST request to you and the request.data would be something like

 [{field1: value1, field2: value2}, {field1: value3, field3:value4}]

How would you use the request.data, because form what I see, bulk_create needs objects as input. Would you put bulk_create in your views or serializers?

Comment: can you show your code you trying in question, for more clearly?